# want to set up a dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi

Problem:

I wanted to make it a dual boot system, however I am unable to get the machine to boot from either the disc or a bootable USB drive. I have disabled the safe boot mode, but still to no avail.

I recently purchased a Dell Inspiron 15 this is the configuration:

- Operating System:Windows 10 Home (x64) Version 1909 (build 18363.900)
- Install Language: English (United States)
- System Locale: English (United States)
- Installed: 6/18/2020 12:39:21
- Servicing Branch: Current Branch (CB)
- Boot Mode: UEFI with Secure Boot disabled
- System Model: Dell Inc. Inspiron 3593
- System Service Tag: xxxxxxx (support for this PC)
- Chassis Serial Number: xxxxxx
- Enclosure Type: Notebook
- Processor:

  - 1.20 gigahertz Intel Core i3-1005G1
  - primary memory cache: 160 kilobyte
  - secondary memory cache:1024 kilobyte
  - tertiary memory cache:4096 kilobyte
  - 64-bit ready
  - Multi-core (2 total)
  - Hyper-threaded (4 total)
- Main Circuit Board b

  - Board: Dell Inc. 0TGVJN A00
  - Serial Number: /384VT33/CNCMC0005C0388/
  - Bus Clock: 100 megahertz
  - UEFI: Dell Inc. 1.5.0 12/17/2019
- Drives

  - 1046.40 Gigabytes Usable Hard Drive Capacity
  - 994.02 Gigabytes Hard Drive Free Space

```
PC SN520 NVMe WDC 128GB [Hard drive] (128.03 GB) -- drive 1, s/n 

20097B451509, SMART Status: Healthy
ST1000LM035-1RK172 [Hard drive] (1000.20 GB) -- drive 0, s/n ZDEJNJS5, rev 1002, SMART Status: Healthy
Memory Modules c,d
7960 Megabytes Usable Installed Memory

Slot 'DIMM A' has 8192 MB (serial number 43634603)
Slot 'DIMM B' is Empty
Local Drive Volumes

c: (NTFS on drive 1) * 46.33 GB 5.11 GB free

d: (NTFS on drive 0) 1000.07 GB 988.91 GB free
```

Comment: Have you updated UEFI from Dell, even new system may have update available. And update to SSD firmware? How did you make USB installer? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick You want to use Windows tools to shrink the Windows NTFS partition and reboot, so it can run chkdsk. Make sure UEFI has Secure Boot off, USB boot allowed, fast start up off and drives changed to AHCI from Intel RST or RAID. Be sure to boot in UEFI boot mode. Issues often common across many similar models. Dell  Inspiron 3670 UEFI update & AHCI worked
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2412152

Answer (score 0):

Plug-in your usb then go into the UEFI and set boot priority to try usb first.

Check your boot priority in UEFI.